OpenLDAP authentication acts very slow when Active Directory is unreachable
I am currently struggling with my OpenLDAP configuration. I want my OpenLDAP server to host a local database and to act as a proxy to an Active Directory database. Both databases should be merged to centralise authentication.
Through my research, I've discovered slapd-meta to merge multiple databases.
Here is a small schema of what I expect :
                            |--------> Local database (LDIF) "ou=local"
META "dc=example,dc=com" ---|
                            |--------> Proxy Active Directory "cn=Users,dc=addomain,dc=com"

I am able to regroup accounts from both Active Directory and local OpenLDAP databases within the "dc=example,dc=com" domain.
Available accounts within "dc=example,dc=com" :

cn=userad,dc=example,dc=com (From Active Directory database)
cn=userldap,dc=example,dc=com (From local OpenLDAP database)

For my Windows devices, I use pGina to manage user authentication against my OpenLDAP server. Once pGINA is correctly configured, I can easily and quickly connect with all available accounts from AD and LDAP (userad et userldap).
My "only" problem is when the Active Directory server is down or unreachable. I am obviously no longer able to connect with Active Directory accounts. However, authentication with OpenLDAP accounts (userldap) becomes very slow and sometimes I can't connect.
In fact, OpenLDAP server keeps trying to reach Active Directory for every request even if it's unreachable. This behaviour seems to slow the OpenLDAP searches within the local LDAP database a lot.
I've tried implementing different types of timeout in order to stop reaching unreachable servers but it doesn't make the authentication for LDAP accounts go any faster.

Here is my slapd.conf :
### SCHEMAS

include         /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/misc.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/microsoft.minimal.schema 
include         /etc/ldap/schema/rfc2307bis.schema

### MODULES 
modulepath      /usr/lib/ldap   #Path
moduleload      back_ldap   #Module for ldap database
moduleload      back_meta   #Module for meta database

### MAIN SETTINGS

pidfile         /run/slapd/slapd.pid
argsfile        /run/slapd/slapd.args

### DATABASES DEFINITION

## GENERAL ##
    
## LOCAL DATABASE CONFIG ##
Database        ldif
suffix                      "ou=local"
directory                   "/var/lib/ldap"
rootdn                      "cn=ldapadm,ou=local"
rootpw                      "*****"

access to *
        by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
        by * read
        by * search


## MAIN DATABASE TO REGROUP BOTH REMOTE AND LOCAL DATABASE##
database        meta
suffix          "dc=example,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
rootpw          "*****"


## PROXY TO LOCAL DB ##
uri                     "ldap://127.0.0.1/dc=example,dc=com"
lastmod                 off
suffixmassage           "dc=example,dc=com" "ou=local"
rebind-as-user
idassert-bind           bindmethod=simple
                        binddn="cn=ldapadm,ou=local"
                        credentials="*****"
                        mode=none
idassert-authzFrom      "*"

## PROXY TO Active Directory ##
uri                     "ldap://AD-ip:389/dc=example,dc=com"
readonly                yes
lastmod                 off
suffixmassage           "dc=example,dc=com" "cn=Users,dc=addomain,dc=com"
protocol-version        3
rebind-as-user
idassert-bind           bindmethod=simple
                        binddn="cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=addomain,dc=com"   
                        credentials="*****"
                        mode=none
                        flags=override
idassert-authzFrom      "*"

map     attribute       uid     sAMAccountName  

Any help or suggestion on how to authenticate with local OpenLDAP accounts even if the Active Directory server is down would be appreciated.
Have a good day.
Krisix
